# Spring Boot and @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like (if possible) to use `@ConfigurationProperties` to create dynamic sized list of POJOs. Please advice whether this is possible. My idea was something like follows (no-args constructors/getter/setters omitted):

The property file:

```
my.item[0].prop1=a
my.item[0].prop2=b

my.item[1].prop1=a
my.item[1].prop2=b
```

And the bean which should be populated:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
public class ItemsConfig {

    private List<Item> items;

    public static class Item {
        private String prop1;
        private String prop2;
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly when I `@Autowire` the `ItemsConfig` the list is always `null`.

Can something similar be achieved with `@ConfigurationProeprties`?

I found a workaround with `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`iterating over properties and creating everything manually bit its horrible code :(

Please advice

PS: I do use `@EnableConfigurationProperties` on my `@Configuration`

**Note:** Once resolved I though people may find useful to realize that the `@EnableConfigurationProperties`annotation must be found and processed before the component with `@ConfigurationProperties`is created by spring. Otherwise the bean won't be populated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small problem with the property entries, it should be the following:

```
my.items[0].prop1=a
my.items[0].prop2=b

my.items[1].prop1=a
my.items[1].prop2=b
```

Note the `items` vs `item`, to match the setter name

Comment: Could it be that easy :) Let me try!